# How do I get an Angular 2 link to be blue and underlined?

Tags: angular

I have the following code in a template of mine:

```
<a (click)="delete(book)">Delete</a>
```

The link works but it doesn't *look* right.

Of course don't need it to actually be blue and underlined, I just didn't know how else to ask the question. I want the link to look like a link.

I have another link (a `routerLink`) that *does* look like a link, so I'm hoping I don't have to resort to CSS to make my delete link look right. It would seem weird (and lame) to me if I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that this works:

```
<a routerLink="" (click)="delete(book)">Delete</a>
```

Comment: This actually redirected me to the homepage of my site - not what I wanted

Answer (score 5):

Please note link to be a link, it is necessary to have `href` attribute to the link. Angular2's `routeLink` behind the scene adds `href` attribute to the link.
Here it seems like you are not interested to use `routerLink` so I think you should add `href="javascript:void(0)"` to the link.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="delete(book)">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Seems kinda weird to have to add `href="javascript:void(0)"` to every link like this, no?

Comment: It could be but without adding `href="javascript:void(0)"` or `routerLink` its not an actual link.

Comment: FYI `routerLink` behind the scene adds `href` to the link.

Comment: What you say isn't wrong. It just seems like a link that "does something" and opposed to goes somewhere must be a super common desire in Angular, and it seems unlikely to me that adding `href="javascript:void(0)"` to those links would be the standard solution. If your answer turns out to be correct, I'll certainly select it, but I'll also be perplexed as to why the Angular team made what is to me such a clearly strange design decision.

Comment: But how can you expected something to happen when something is not present? In your case nothing (`href or routeLink`) is mentioned.

Comment: You can also add `href="#"` if you wish. But I haven't checked it yet.

Comment: I figured out that if I do `<a routerLink="" (click)="delete(book)">Delete</a>`, it looks/works the way I want. If you feel inclined to change your answer to that, I'll accept that, otherwise I'll plan to add my own answer. I definitely don't disagree with anything you're saying, I just find it unpalatable to have to use `href="javascript:void(0)"` or `href="#"`, the latter of which of course adds a `#` to my URL which is undesirable to me.

Comment: Nope.Its okay. You make your own answer. I don't agree with your solution as it finally adds `href` to the link. Why you want `angular2` to take that responsibility when you don't need it actually. Why to make some overload? native support is already there which is mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I haven't tested `routeLink=" "` but what I feel like is it may fail in some cases when you have `' '` route or path, not sure though.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. To address your most recent comment, I do happen to have a `''` route and having `routerLink=""` doesn't seem to interfere with it.

Comment: Okay then good to go. But I still don't prefer it as it is not menitoned/written anywhere and at last, again saying, it adds `href`to the link. it will add `href="something" or href=""` which can unintentionally cause the problem later not sure again. So best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

By default Angular 2 components have their style sort of encapsulated, perhaps try adding:

```
 a {color: blue; text-decoration: underline;}
```